# Is always $\small {rq-1 \over 2^B} \le q-1 $ with natural r,q,B and $\small r,q \in \{1, \ldots, (2^B-1)\} , odd$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Consider the comparision in positive integers $$\small {rq-1 \over 2^B} \le q-1 $$ where $\small B $ is the given parameter and *r* and *q* are residues modulo $\small 2^B$ (which also implies, that the lhs is assumed to be integer and which then puts restrictions on the relation of *r* and *q*) .
In my calculations I use $\small r=3^N (\mod 2^B) $and $\small q=3^{-N} (\mod 2^B) $ with $\small N \gt 0$ as free parameter to guarantee an integer lhs. (This implicitely restricts empirical results to less possible residue classes in *r,q* and thus possible solutions, but leave this for the moment).

My observation is, that the lhs is always at most equal to the rhs, which makes me curious. But I was not yet able to extract the key argument, why this is so. It is easy to see, that if $\small q=2^B-1 $ then also $\small r=q $ (from which then the **equality** in the equation follows) and also if $\small q=1 $ then $\small r=1$ and again the **equality** holds.

So my question is, how can I see that the given inequality holds always?

Comment: You talk about $p$, but I don't see it anywhere.

Comment: @Gerry: It's meant *r*. I'll correct it

Comment: $p$ is still there.

Comment: Just found and removed that last easter-egg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, I don't know why I didn't see this before ....

Assume $\small {rq-1\over 2^B}=q$ then  $\small rq=q2^B+1$ and $\small r=2^B+\frac1q $ .
Here the case *q=1* gives the only integer solution $\small r=2^B+1 $, but which as well as the noninteger solutions due to $\small q \gt 1$ are excluded by the definitions.

[update] It is even nicer; empirically I find, that $$\small {rq-1\over 2^B}+1 \le \min({q,r})$$ and equality occurs if and only if *q* or *r* is a divisor of $\small 2^B-1 $ . (Recall $\small r\equiv 1/q \pmod {2^B} $) This is really a surprise!

Comment: To remove the uestion from the automatic reminder I've to "accept" one answer formally. I'll do that although it's my own answer...