# A Special Case of Loops in Collatz Conjecture

Tags: elementary-number-theory, collatz-conjecture

I want to show that there can't be simple loops in the Collatz conjecture over positive numbers, where you began with an odd number n, then after applying $\frac{3n+1}{2}$ then you repeat the process until you get to an even number. When it arrives at an even number the number is in the form $\mathrm{2}^cn$ (c integer). So dividing by $\mathrm{2}^c$ will complete the loop. (Execpt case $n=1$)

What I have tried:
Write n in the form $n=\mathrm{2}^b(2a-1)-1$ (n can be written in this form since any odd number can be written in this form.)

Applying $\frac{3n+1}{2}$ yeilds: $\frac{3((2a-1)\mathrm{2}^b-1)+1}{2} = \frac{3(2a-1)\mathrm{2}^b-3+1}{2} = \frac{3(2a-1)\mathrm{2}^b-2}{2} = {3(2a-1)\mathrm{2}^{b-1}-1}$

Which is still odd if $b>1$ and this process can be applied b times before an even number is output. Which yields $\mathrm{3}^b(2a+1)-1$

The desired form of the loop gives: $\mathrm{3}^b(2a+1)-1=\mathrm{2}^c(\mathrm{2}^b(2a+1)-1)$ I believe showing there are no solutions in natural numbers (besides the case corresponding to n=1) would solve the problem, but I am unable to find a way to prove that.

Can it be shown that there is no solutions to this equation or is there an easier approach?

Comment: You should perhaps say this would exclude simple loops.  It would not exclude more  complicated loops.  Both exist in negative numbers  such as $−1 → −2 → −1$ as an example of the kind of simple loop you are looking at and $−5 → −14 → −7 → −20 → −10 → −5$ as an example of a kind of complicated loop with more of a mixture of odds and evens.

Comment: It is already known that a possible loop must contain many many "ups" and "downs" and in total must be extremely long. The case of a 1-loop is known since a long time, but I do not know where a proof can be read.

Comment: Any loop other than the loop with 1 in it, has a minimum value that is 3 mod 4. Have you tried using that ?

Comment: Perhaps an interesting question with same question-focus. Contains workout of std. formulae and of some seldom seen properties. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/187922/1714 (Does *not* provide the complete proof of non-existence of 1-cycles though)

Comment: A disproof of the 1-cycle using the central tool that Steiner and later Simons/deWeger use, but does not need the part of the continued fraction. See https://go.helms-net.de/math/collatz/Collatz_1cycledisproof.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ray P Steiner, A theorem on the Syracuse problem, Proc. 7th Manitoba Conference on Numerical Mathematics and Computing (Univ. Manitoba-Winnipeg 1977), Congressus Numerantium XX, Utilitas Math. (1978) 553-559, MR 80g:10003 proved that the only positive loop of the type under discussion is the one starting at $1$ (allowing negative integers, there's also the one starting at $-1$, and the one starting at $-5$). According to Lagarias' annotated bibliography, the problem reduces to finding positive integer solutions to
$$
(2^{k+\ell}-3^k)h=2^{\ell}-1. 
$$
Steiner shows that the only solution in positive integers is $(k,\ell,h)=(1,1,1)$. The proof uses results from transcendence theory, Baker's method of linear forms in logarithms (which won Baker a Fields medal, so you see what you are up against).

Many have tried to find Steiner's paper on the web, no one I know of has succeeded. Interlibrary loan should work. Also, no one I know of has succeeded in finding a proof simpler than Steiner's.

Comment: This might unintentionally suggest Steiner proved the known negative exceptions/examples (of this form) are canonical. I've no idea if that is true. But you would imagine his work would translate in a straightforward way to $3x-1$ thereby giving a result over negative numbers.